# Prevent scrolling of parent element when inner element scroll position reaches top/bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, event-bubbling, event-propagation

I have a little "floating tool box" - a div with `position:fixed; overflow:auto`.
Works just fine.

But when scrolling inside that box (with the mouse wheel) and reaching the bottom OR top, the parent element "takes over" the "scroll request" : The document behind the tool box scrolls.
- Which is annoying and not what the user "asked for".

I'm using jQuery and thought I could stop this behaviour with event.stoppropagation():
`$("#toolBox").scroll( function(event){ event.stoppropagation() });`

It does enter the function, but still, propagation happens anyway (the document scrolls)
- It's surprisingly hard to search for this topic on SO (and Google), so I have to ask:
How to prevent propagation / bubbling of the scroll-event ?

Edit:
Working solution thanks to amustill (and Brandon Aaron for the mousewheel-plugin here:
https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/raw/master/jquery.mousewheel.js

```
$(".ToolPage").bind('mousewheel', function(e, d)  
    var t = $(this);
    if (d > 0 && t.scrollTop() === 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        if (d < 0 && (t.scrollTop() == t.get(0).scrollHeight - t.innerHeight())) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks like it might not be possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459676/prevent-scroll-bubbling-from-element-to-window

Comment: @Musaul - actually that thread gave 2 possible solutions (if a bit rouge): setting `overflow:hidden` on the document, when hovering in the toolbox, or saving the documents scrollTop, and forcing it upon the document repeatedly (nice), during toolbox.scroll()...

Comment: Yeah, I meant the scroll event bubbling. But I suppose it gives you workarounds. I'd completely avoid the scroll forcing option though. Doing too much (or anything in complex pages) in the scroll event can make the browser freeze for a while, especially on slower computers.

Comment: This works beautifully in everything other than IE, when attached to the body tag. With the above fix, it seems to disable mousewheel scrolling entirely.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer, @Matthew. It resolves the IE issue, as well as normalizing for FireFox without any plug-ins.

Comment: this is more than you asked for, and there are more than enough answers posted below, but I wrote a script a'la "hover intent" for jQuery, which tracks the user's [mouse-wheel intent](http://jsbin.com/ORoCozi/4/edit)

Comment: The solution at this question is far simpler and far better in most cases: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211203/scrolling-child-div-scrolls-the-window-how-do-i-stop-that

Comment: This doesn't work if user uses up and down arrow from the keyboard to scroll.

Comment: This question shouldn't have been closed - the "duplicate" question specifically asks for scrolling in an iframe and has answers just for dealing with an iframe.

Comment: Brandon Aaron's plugin link is 404

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's possible with the use of Brandon Aaron's [Mousewheel plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/mousewheel/).

Here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/jivutakama/edit?html,js,output

```
$(function() {

  var toolbox = $('#toolbox'),
      height = toolbox.height(),
      scrollHeight = toolbox.get(0).scrollHeight;

  toolbox.bind('mousewheel', function(e, d) {
    if((this.scrollTop === (scrollHeight - height) && d < 0) || (this.scrollTop === 0 && d > 0)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: YES! It works in both FF and Chrome, but not (at all) in Opera for some reason..

Comment: Got it - in opera the d (direction) is -0.666 or 0.666 instead of -1 or 1) - so checking for d<0 or d>0 fixes it : )

Comment: I've issued a fix that now works in Opera. http://jsbin.com/ixura3/3

Comment: Great minds. That's exactly what my fix does.

Comment: This works for trapping the event, although I did find a minor issue with the condition to trigger preventDefault: for some elements like <ul> the "scrollTop" at the bottom of the list is off by a few (four) pixels consistently in different browsers.

I may be doing something else wrong, but I found I could work around by modifying the condition - instead of
 "scrollHeight - height == this.scrollTop", 
I used 
"scrollHeight - height - scrollTop < 5".

Comment: Whoops, those 4 pixels are accounted for in the difference between innerHeight.

Comment: There's also some weirdness if you have scrolling inertia on and scroll a child container and then move your mouse out of the child. The inertia caries onto the parent or any other container. I experienced this on a magic mouse in chrome on OSX Lion

Comment: Works well in FF, IE.
It works using the scrollwheel in chrome, but if you use the arrow keys then scroll events still bubble up to the parent.

Comment: If you have dynamic content under your div this code is not working use this instead $('#divImageMain').bind('mousewheel', function(e, d) {
        if((this.scrollTop === (this.scrollHeight - $(this).height()) && d < 0) || (this.scrollTop === 0 && d > 0)) {
           e.preventDefault();
        }
      });

Comment: the jsbin examples do not prevent page scrolling on an iPad.

Comment: @Heraldmonkey I'm aware of this issue. I hope to have time to revise the answer for all browsers and device.

Comment: The jsbin example is not working for me on an osx trackpad

Comment: Not working for me on Mac OS X and Chrome 32.

Comment: Not working on Windows 7 with Chrome 39

Comment: It is not working because the mousewheel code is loaded as 'text/plain'. If you place the code directly inside the script tag it will works. Yet please read the answer below by Troy Alford. And accepted
 answer != best answer.

Comment: The demo provided at http://output.jsbin.com/ixura3/3 is not working anymore (Chrome 45)

Comment: This of course only works on a desktop with a device that fires mousewheel events. If you switch to a touch device, the the scrolling using touch gestures will scroll the parent when the child is scrolled to its boundary.

Comment: for d < 0 use `abs(st - (sh - $(scrollable).height())) < 1` to avoid subpixel problems

Answer (score 177):

I am adding this answer for completeness because **the accepted answer by @amustill does not correctly solve the problem in Internet Explorer**. Please see the comments in [my original post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16324663/1454806) for details. In addition, this solution does not require any plugins - only jQuery.

In essence, the code works by handling the `mousewheel` event. Each such event contains a `wheelDelta` equal to the number of `px` which it is going to move the scrollable area to. If this value is `>0`, then we are scrolling `up`. If the `wheelDelta` is `<0` then we are scrolling `down`.

**FireFox**: FireFox uses `DOMMouseScroll` as the event, and populates `originalEvent.detail`, whose `+/-` is reversed from what is described above. It generally returns intervals of `3`, while other browsers return scrolling in intervals of `120` (at least on my machine). To correct, we simply detect it and multiply by `-40` to normalize.

[@amustill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5802887/1454806) works by canceling the event if the `<div>`'s scrollable area is already either at the top or the bottom maximum position. However, *Internet Explorer* disregards the canceled event in situations where the `delta` is larger than the remaining scrollable space.

In other words, if you have a `200px` tall `<div>` containing `500px` of scrollable content, and the current `scrollTop` is `400`, a `mousewheel` event which tells the browser to scroll `120px` further will result in both the `<div>` and the `<body>` scrolling, because `400` + `120` > `500`.

So - to solve the problem, we have to do something slightly different, as shown below:

The requisite `jQuery` code is:

```
$(document).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', '.Scrollable', function(ev) {
    var $this = $(this),
        scrollTop = this.scrollTop,
        scrollHeight = this.scrollHeight,
        height = $this.innerHeight(),
        delta = (ev.type == 'DOMMouseScroll' ?
            ev.originalEvent.detail * -40 :
            ev.originalEvent.wheelDelta),
        up = delta > 0;

    var prevent = function() {
        ev.stopPropagation();
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.returnValue = false;
        return false;
    }

    if (!up && -delta > scrollHeight - height - scrollTop) {
        // Scrolling down, but this will take us past the bottom.
        $this.scrollTop(scrollHeight);
        return prevent();
    } else if (up && delta > scrollTop) {
        // Scrolling up, but this will take us past the top.
        $this.scrollTop(0);
        return prevent();
    }
});
```

In essence, this code cancels any scrolling event which would create the unwanted edge condition, then uses jQuery to set the `scrollTop` of the `<div>` to either the maximum or minimum value, depending on which direction the `mousewheel` event was requesting.

Because the event is canceled entirely in either case, it never propagates to the `body` at all, and therefore solves the issue in IE, as well as all of the other browsers.

I have also put up a [working example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wrxq/272/).

Comment: This is, by far, the most comprehensive answer. I made your function into a jQuery extension, so it can be used inline in a jQuery object chain. See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/theftprevention/5959411).

Comment: Nice - thanks for sharing that, and for the kudos. :)

Comment: Excellent, comprehensive and easy to understand answer.

Comment: This works very well, but there seems to be an inertia problem when scrolling really fast. The page is still scrolled by about 20 pixels, which is not too bad.

Comment: There should be `$this.scrollTop(scrollHeight - height);` for the first case.

Comment: This worked out great for me. But for some reason it does not work on iFrames in IE. At least that's what it looks like to me. Here's a fiddle of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/4wrxq/84/ I've experienced this issue in IE9 and IE10. It works fine in Chrome.

Comment: Tested in FF on a fixed position div, it stopped scrolling  completely, even on target.

Comment: Can you post a Fiddle of that behavior? I suspect that FF, which has a non-standard implementation compared to all other browsers I've tested with, reports mouse events differently over Fixed-Position elements. I'd like to confirm, though, that your scenario is, in fact, different than in Chrome or IE.

Comment: Don't lock scrolling if the content doesn't overflow: `if (this.scrollHeight <= parseInt($(this).css("max-height"))) return` as the first line in the function.

Comment: That's precisely what the `if`/`then` statement at the end does. Unless I'm misunderstanding, this addition would be superfluous.

Comment: This worked great for me with a minor change. I found that setting the element's height to $this.height() wasn't responding properly to the bottom of an element if it had paddings/margins. So I changed it to $this.outerHeight(true).

Comment: What about touch move

Comment: Example doesn't work when user scrolls via trackpad or via touch on touch-enabled devices.

Comment: If you don't understand the jsFiddle example, add more <li> elements to the outer container so it is given a scrollbar, too. My monitor was high enough so there wasn't any.

Comment: @T4NK3R It's not always desired - you still don't want your right-now-background elements to scroll when you use the possibly scrollable list.

Comment: Must be careful when `.Scrollable` has set a `padding-top` or `padding-bottom`. You need to calculate into scroll down condition

Comment: Thank you! It worked nicely for me on Mac OS X, trackpad and Chrome. It worked only sometimes in Firefox.

Comment: does this also work on touch scrolling?

Comment: Sorry, Mr. Moe - I'm not sure, as I haven't tested it for that. (This answer was posted in 2013)

Comment: Excellent.. Totally fixed my slimScroll.

Comment: Woot! Glad to hear it, @NiallMurphy!

Comment: This solution doesn't work in Firefox. But if you change event to `wheel` and change the rest of the script to use `event.deltaY` instead of delta or wheelDelta then it would. Gist to demonstrate: https://gist.github.com/s-mage/bca26b996f193f94fdf789d8324c5c7b

Answer (score 65):

**TL;DR: You can safely use [`overscroll-behavior: contain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior) to achieve this on modern browsers.**

---

All the solutions given in this thread don't mention an existing - and native - way to solve this problem without reordering DOM and/or using event preventing tricks. But there's a good reason: this way is proprietary - and available on MS web platform only. Quoting [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772034(v=vs.85).aspx):

> ***-ms-scroll-chaining*** property - specifies the scrolling behavior that occurs when a user hits the scroll limit during a manipulation. Property values:
>
> **chained** - Initial value. The nearest scrollable parent element begins scrolling when the user hits a scroll limit during a manipulation. No bounce effect is shown.
>
> **none** - A bounce effect is shown when the user hits a scroll limit during a manipulation.

Granted, this property is supported on IE10+/Edge only. Still, here's a [**telling quote**](https://github.com/WICG/overscroll-behavior):

> To give you a sense of how popular preventing scroll chaining may be,
> according to my quick http-archive search "-ms-scroll-chaining: none"
> is used in 0.4% of top 300K pages despite being limited in
> functionality and only supported on IE/Edge.

And now good news, everyone! Starting from Chrome 63, we finally have a native cure for Blink-based platforms too - and that's both Chrome (obviously) and Android WebView (soon).

Quoting [**the introducing article**](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/overscroll-behavior):

> The **overscroll-behavior** property is a new CSS feature that controls
> the behavior of what happens when you over-scroll a container
> (including the page itself). You can use it to cancel scroll chaining,
> disable/customize the pull-to-refresh action, disable rubberbanding
> effects on iOS (when Safari implements overscroll-behavior), and more.[...]
>
> The property takes three possible values:
>
> **auto** - Default. Scrolls that originate on the element may propagate to
> ancestor elements.
>
> **contain** - prevents scroll chaining. Scrolls do not
> propagate to ancestors but local effects within the node are shown.
> For example, the overscroll glow effect on Android or the
> rubberbanding effect on iOS which notifies the user when they've hit a
> scroll boundary. Note: using overscroll-behavior: contain on the html
> element prevents overscroll navigation actions.
>
> **none** - same as contain but it also prevents overscroll effects within the node itself (e.g. Android overscroll glow or iOS rubberbanding).
>
> [...] **The best part is that using overscroll-behavior does not adversely
> affect page performance like the hacks mentioned in the intro!**

Here's this [**feature in action**](https://ebidel.github.io/demos/chatbox.html). And here's corresponding [**CSS Module document**](https://wicg.github.io/overscroll-behavior/).

**UPDATE:** Firefox, since version 59, has joined the club, and MS Edge is expected to implement this feature in version 18. Here's the corresponding [**caniusage**](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-overscroll-behavior).

**UPDATE 2:** And now (Oct, 2022) Safari officially joined the club: since 16.0 version, `overscroll-behavior` is [no longer behind the feature flag](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-16-release-notes).

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=overscroll-behavior I guess it will get better in the future

Comment: Safari doesn't support `overscroll-behavior`.

Comment: This strategy doesn’t seem to be effective on an inner element that doesn’t itself have enough content to be scrollable.

Comment: Since Safari 14.1, the feature is behind a flag and can be enabled in the "Experimental Features" developer menu. So most probably, they will enable this feature some time in the future ...

Comment: @raina77ow Since this property has good support now I recommend cleaning up this answer to make it more clear

Comment: However I like this approach, - it has an inconsistency, and no way around it. Namely, if the area is "scrollable" but does not have enough content for the scrollbar to show up, the event isn't prevented from popping. For some, it might be desirable, sure, but there is certainly a number of scenarios where consistency is preferable.

Answer (score 28):

I know it's quite an old question, but since this is one of top results in google... I had to somehow cancel scroll bubbling without jQuery and this code works for me:

```
function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault)
    e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;  
}

document.getElementById('a').onmousewheel = function(e) { 
  document.getElementById('a').scrollTop -= e. wheelDeltaY; 
  preventDefault(e);
}
```

Comment: interesting idea, ..the mousewheel event is not cross-browser though, and the scroll distance needs to be normalised, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5542105/126600

Comment: We can have nested views, which makes it buggy.

Comment: Does this work with mobile touch? Thanks

Comment: @AGamePlayer definitelly not, because touch devices won't be firing *mousewheel* events unless you'd actually be using a mouse on them. Otherwise they do the normal scrolling. You might be lucky (ab)using touch events though...

Answer (score 19):

EDIT: [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yejxXM)

For AngularJS, I defined the following directive:

```
module.directive('isolateScrolling', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        element.bind('DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
          if (e.detail > 0 && this.clientHeight + this.scrollTop == this.scrollHeight) {
            this.scrollTop = this.scrollHeight - this.clientHeight;
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
          }
          else if (e.detail < 0 && this.scrollTop <= 0) {
            this.scrollTop = 0;
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
          }
        });
        element.bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
          if (e.deltaY > 0 && this.clientHeight + this.scrollTop >= this.scrollHeight) {
            this.scrollTop = this.scrollHeight - this.clientHeight;
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
          }
          else if (e.deltaY < 0 && this.scrollTop <= 0) {
            this.scrollTop = 0;
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
          }

          return true;
        });
      }
  };
});
```

And then added it to the scrollable element (the dropdown-menu ul):

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle">Rename <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" isolate-scrolling>
    <li ng-repeat="s in savedSettings | objectToArray | orderBy:'name' track by s.name">
      <a ng-click="renameSettings(s.name)">{{s.name}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Tested on Chrome and Firefox. Chrome's smooth scrolling defeats this hack when a large mousewheel movement is made near (but not at) the top or bottom of the scroll region.

Comment: This does not appear to be working in Chrome 34. The binding is firing, but the page continues to scroll when the `<ul>` reaches the bottom.

Comment: It's working for me in Chrome 36.

Comment: Doesn't work on Firefox or IE though, and neither it does after you add `DOMMouseScroll`.

Comment: it works for me, but the values are inverted ;)

Just change > 0 with < 0 and vice versa. Tested on Windows 8.1, with chrome, firefox and ie11

Comment: I'm wondering if that has to do with a change in how the origin of the element is represented? The code assumes that the origin is at the top.

Comment: I've discovered that this doesn't fully work when Chrome's smooth scrolling is enabled. Since that causes the scrollTop to be animated over time, when the wheel event is processed the scrollTop doesn't appear to be at the top or bottom of the scroll region, so it lets the event through.

Comment: I've added Firefox support, tested with FF 39.

Comment: Works perfect, but for me it doesn't work if I use name 'isolateScrolling' but 'isolatescrolling' works =) Thanks for life save. Also I've added some costom code to detect if my dynamic ul has scroll, and if has then prevent DOM scroll. `if (element.prop('offsetHeight') < element.prop('scrollHeight')) {
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        e.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    }`

Comment: working, only difference I use is change e.deltaY for e.originalEvent.deltaY
not sure why...
why you use differents binds instead a single function? worked for me... tested on FF chrome safari

Comment: @ppollono As I recall, the event attributes differ between FF and Chrome. Are you saying that FF and Safari trigger the `mousewheel` event and not `DOMMouseScroll`?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yejxXM -- tested with Chrome 47 and Firefox 41.

Comment: Any interest in putting this on Github and creating a package on npm/bower?

Comment: Do you have it supported in further version of angular like 6 or 7.

Comment: sorry, I don't use newer versions of angular

Answer (score 13):

There are tons of questions like this out there, with many answers, but I could not find a satisfactory solution that did not involve events, scripts, plugins, etc.  I wanted to keep it straight in HTML and CSS.  I finally found a solution that worked, although it involved restructuring the markup to break the event chain.

---

**1. Basic problem**

Scrolling input (i.e.: mousewheel) applied to the modal element will spill over into an ancestor element and scroll it in the same direction, if some such element is scrollable:

*(All examples are meant to be viewed on desktop resolutions)*

https://jsfiddle.net/ybkbg26c/5/

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="modal">
    This text is pretty long here.  Hope fully, we will get some scroll bars.
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#modal {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#parent {
  height: 4000px;
}
```

---

**2. No parent scroll on modal scroll**

The reason why the ancestor ends up scrolling is because the scroll event bubbles and some element on the chain *is able to* handle it.  A way to stop that is to make sure none of the elements on the chain know how to handle the scroll.  In terms of our example, we can refactor the tree to move the modal out of the parent element.  For obscure reasons, it is not enough to keep the parent and the modal DOM siblings; the parent must be wrapped by another element that establishes a new stacking context.  An absolutely positioned wrapper around the parent can do the trick.

The result we get is that as long as the modal receives the scroll event, the event will not bubble to the "parent" element.

It should typically be possible to redesign the DOM tree to support this behavior without affecting what the end user sees.

https://jsfiddle.net/0bqq31Lv/3/

HTML:

```
<div id="context">
  <div id="parent">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="modal">
  This text is pretty long here.  Hope fully, we will get some scroll bars.
</div>
```

CSS (new only):

```
#context {
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

---

**3. No scroll anywhere except in modal while it is up**

The solution above still allows the parent to receive scroll events, as long as they are not intercepted by the modal window (i.e. if triggered by mousewheel while the cursor is not over the modal).  This is sometimes undesirable and we may want to forbid all background scrolling while the modal is up.  To do that, we need to insert an extra stacking context that spans the whole viewport behind the modal.  We can do that by displaying an absolutely positioned overlay, which can be fully transparent if necessary (but not `visibility:hidden`).

https://jsfiddle.net/0bqq31Lv/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="context">
  <div id="parent">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="overlay">  
</div>
<div id="modal">
  This text is pretty long here.  Hope fully, we will get some scroll bars.
</div>
```

CSS (new on top of #2):

```
#overlay {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: The basic problem arises when the "modal" IS the child of another scrollable element - scripting seems unavoidable.. In my original code the toolbox was just one of several - each in a separate tab (COULD probably be moved to <body> - but that would be BIG)

Comment: @T4NK3R Yes, there are tradeoffs.  In my case refactoring the DOM was by far preferable to throwing UI javascript onto the problem.  Overall, I think this is an option worth contemplating for someone who designs their tree from scratch.

Comment: This is the only approach that effectively avoids the issue instead of trying to fix a problem with tons of JS that could have been avoided from the start.

Comment: I've read dozens of answers to this issue, many of them with 100+ points. This is the only one that actually makes sense.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a plain JavaScript version:

```
function scroll(e) {
  var delta = (e.type === "mousewheel") ? e.wheelDelta : e.detail * -40;
  if (delta < 0 && (this.scrollHeight - this.offsetHeight - this.scrollTop) <= 0) {
    this.scrollTop = this.scrollHeight;
    e.preventDefault();
  } else if (delta > 0 && delta > this.scrollTop) {
    this.scrollTop = 0;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
document.querySelectorAll(".scroller").addEventListener("mousewheel", scroll);
document.querySelectorAll(".scroller").addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scroll);
```

Comment: Nice solution. Works great in chrome

Comment: I was having issue with firefox, this solution worked.

Answer (score 9):

As variant, to avoid performance issues with `scroll` or `mousewheel` handling, you can use code like below:

css:

```
body.noscroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.scrollable {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="scrollable">
...A bunch of items to make the div scroll...
</div>
...A bunch of text to make the body scroll...
```

js:

```
var $document = $(document),
    $body = $('body'),
    $scrolable = $('.scrollable');

$scrolable.on({
          'mouseenter': function () {
            // add hack class to prevent workspace scroll when scroll outside
            $body.addClass('noscroll');
          },
          'mouseleave': function () {
            // remove hack class to allow scroll
            $body.removeClass('noscroll');
          }
        });
```

Example of work: http://jsbin.com/damuwinarata/4

Comment: The scrolls when is hide in some browsers move all the page to left because scroll disappear...

Answer (score 9):

#### Angular JS Directive

I had to wrap an angular directive. The following is a Mashup of the other answers here. tested on Chrome and Internet Explorer 11.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.directive("preventParentScroll", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, elm, attr) {
            elm.bind('mousewheel', onMouseWheel);
            function onMouseWheel(e) {
                elm[0].scrollTop -= (e.wheelDeltaY || (e.originalEvent && (e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta)) || e.wheelDelta || 0);
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                e.returnValue = false;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Usage

```
<div prevent-parent-scroll>
    ...
</div>
```

---

Hopes this helps the next person that gets here from a Google search.

Comment: I really like the solution, it's working good. I just had to change one thing in angular 1.5. As e.originalEvet is not needed, just read wheel deltas directly from the e. (for both, wheelDeltaY and wheelDelta)

Comment: @Tom thanks for your feedback. i think `e.originalEvent` is for supporting IE

Comment: Hmm interesting, it sounds like IE. I will check it when I will be around win machine.

Answer (score 7):

Using native element scroll properties with the delta value from the mousewheel plugin:

```
$elem.on('mousewheel', function (e, delta) {
    // Restricts mouse scrolling to the scrolling range of this element.
    if (
        this.scrollTop < 1 && delta > 0 ||
        (this.clientHeight + this.scrollTop) === this.scrollHeight && delta < 0
    ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this outcome with CSS, ie

```
.isolate-scrolling {
    overscroll-behavior: contain;
}
```

This will only scroll the parent container if your mouse leaves the child element to the parent.

Answer (score 6):

In case someone is still looking for a solution for this, the following plugin does the job http://mohammadyounes.github.io/jquery-scrollLock/

It fully addresses the issue of locking mouse wheel scroll inside a given container, preventing it from propagating to parent element.

It does not change wheel scrolling speed, user experience will not be affected. and you get the same behavior regardless of the OS mouse wheel vertical scrolling speed (On Windows it can be set to one screen or one line up to 100 lines per notch).

Demo: http://mohammadyounes.github.io/jquery-scrollLock/example/

Source: https://github.com/MohammadYounes/jquery-scrollLock

Comment: Sounds great, but when I try your demo in either Firefox or Chrome on MacOS, I still see the kind of problematic scrolling behavior described in this question.

Comment: @Ghazgkull Check the General section  in your System Preferences, if "Show Scroll Bars" is set to "When Scrolling", then you need to force it as the library won't be able to detect the presence of scroll-bars (see https://github.com/MohammadYounes/jquery-scrollLock/pull/3).

Answer (score 4):

amustill's answer as a knockout handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.preventParentScroll = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
        $(element).mousewheel(function (e, d) {
            var t = $(this);
            if (d > 0 && t.scrollTop() === 0) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            else {
                if (d < 0 && (t.scrollTop() == t.get(0).scrollHeight - t.innerHeight())) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: I'd add a call to ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback in here too.  I know it's probably not necessary since the node cleanup works between KO and jQuery works pretty well but it's nice to cover your bases :)

Answer (score 4):

the method above is not that natural, after some googling I find a more nice solution , and no need of jQuery. see [1] and demo [2].

```js
  var element = document.getElementById('uf-notice-ul');

  var isMacWebkit = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Macintosh") !== -1 &&
    navigator.userAgent.indexOf("WebKit") !== -1);
  var isFirefox = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("firefox") !== -1);

  element.onwheel = wheelHandler; // Future browsers
  element.onmousewheel = wheelHandler; // Most current browsers
  if (isFirefox) {
    element.scrollTop = 0;
    element.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", wheelHandler, false);
  }
  // prevent from scrolling parrent elements
  function wheelHandler(event) {
    var e = event || window.event; // Standard or IE event object

    // Extract the amount of rotation from the event object, looking
    // for properties of a wheel event object, a mousewheel event object 
    // (in both its 2D and 1D forms), and the Firefox DOMMouseScroll event.
    // Scale the deltas so that one "click" toward the screen is 30 pixels.
    // If future browsers fire both "wheel" and "mousewheel" for the same
    // event, we'll end up double-counting it here. Hopefully, however,
    // cancelling the wheel event will prevent generation of mousewheel.
    var deltaX = e.deltaX * -30 || // wheel event
      e.wheelDeltaX / 4 || // mousewheel
      0; // property not defined
    var deltaY = e.deltaY * -30 || // wheel event
      e.wheelDeltaY / 4 || // mousewheel event in Webkit
      (e.wheelDeltaY === undefined && // if there is no 2D property then 
        e.wheelDelta / 4) || // use the 1D wheel property
      e.detail * -10 || // Firefox DOMMouseScroll event
      0; // property not defined

    // Most browsers generate one event with delta 120 per mousewheel click.
    // On Macs, however, the mousewheels seem to be velocity-sensitive and
    // the delta values are often larger multiples of 120, at 
    // least with the Apple Mouse. Use browser-testing to defeat this.
    if (isMacWebkit) {
      deltaX /= 30;
      deltaY /= 30;
    }
    e.currentTarget.scrollTop -= deltaY;
    // If we ever get a mousewheel or wheel event in (a future version of)
    // Firefox, then we don't need DOMMouseScroll anymore.
    if (isFirefox && e.type !== "DOMMouseScroll") {
      element.removeEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", wheelHandler, false);
    }
    // Don't let this event bubble. Prevent any default action.
    // This stops the browser from using the mousewheel event to scroll
    // the document. Hopefully calling preventDefault() on a wheel event
    // will also prevent the generation of a mousewheel event for the
    // same rotation.
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    e.cancelBubble = true; // IE events
    e.returnValue = false; // IE events
    return false;
  }
```

[1] https://dimakuzmich.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/prevent-scrolling-of-parent-element-with-javascript/

[2] http://jsfiddle.net/dima_k/5mPkB/1/

Comment: Very nice solution - and this one blocks scrolling of the parent, even if the the small container doesn't need scrolling (it's content fits inside) - though some would bark at that - maybe make that feature optional with a second class...?

Comment: Ups, spoke too soon. In my Chrome on W10, scroll jumps straight to the bottom when wheeling down (on your jsfiddle) - that's no good

Answer (score 4):

This actually works in AngularJS. 
Tested on Chrome and Firefox.

```
.directive('stopScroll', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            element.bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
                var $this = $(this),
                    scrollTop = this.scrollTop,
                    scrollHeight = this.scrollHeight,
                    height = $this.height(),
                    delta = (e.type == 'DOMMouseScroll' ?
                    e.originalEvent.detail * -40 :
                        e.originalEvent.wheelDelta),
                    up = delta > 0;

                var prevent = function() {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.returnValue = false;
                    return false;
                };

                if (!up && -delta > scrollHeight - height - scrollTop) {
                    // Scrolling down, but this will take us past the bottom.
                    $this.scrollTop(scrollHeight);
                    return prevent();
                } else if (up && delta > scrollTop) {
                    // Scrolling up, but this will take us past the top.
                    $this.scrollTop(0);
                    return prevent();
                }
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Answer (score 4):

We can simply use CSS.
Give a style to the child scroll container element.

```
 style="overscroll-behavior: contain"
```

It doesn't trigger the parent's scroll event.

Comment: interesting, but at this moment not supported yet by safari: https://caniuse.com/css-overscroll-behavior

Answer (score 2):

my jQuery plugin:

```
$('.child').dontScrollParent();

$.fn.dontScrollParent = function()
{
    this.bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',function(e)
    {
        var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -e.originalEvent.detail;

        if (delta > 0 && $(this).scrollTop() <= 0)
            return false;
        if (delta < 0 && $(this).scrollTop() >= this.scrollHeight - $(this).height())
            return false;

        return true;
    });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar situation and here's how i solved it:
All my scrollable elements get the class *scrollable*.

```
$(document).on('wheel', '.scrollable', function(evt) {
  var offsetTop = this.scrollTop + parseInt(evt.originalEvent.deltaY, 10);
  var offsetBottom = this.scrollHeight - this.getBoundingClientRect().height - offsetTop;

  if (offsetTop < 0 || offsetBottom < 0) {
    evt.preventDefault();
  } else {
    evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
});
```

*stopImmediatePropagation()* makes sure not to scroll parent scrollable area from scrollable child area.

Here's a vanilla JS implementation of it:
http://jsbin.com/lugim/2/edit?js,output

Comment: Can you please clarify what "offsetTop < 0 || offsetBottom < 0" means? What are you actually trying to assert?

Comment: Consider using an intermediary variable to give it a name.

Comment: ... or rename the existing ones, or add some comments to explain.

Comment: If I understand right, you are checking if the element *will be* scrolled to bottom or top boundary if the event should run it's course.

Answer (score 2):

New web dev here. This worked like a charm for me on both IE and Chrome.

```
static preventScrollPropagation(e: HTMLElement) {
    e.onmousewheel = (ev) => {
        var preventScroll = false;
        var isScrollingDown = ev.wheelDelta < 0;
        if (isScrollingDown) {
            var isAtBottom = e.scrollTop + e.clientHeight == e.scrollHeight;
            if (isAtBottom) {
                preventScroll = true;
            }
        } else {
            var isAtTop = e.scrollTop == 0;
            if (isAtTop) {
                preventScroll = true;
            }
        }
        if (preventScroll) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Don't let the number of lines fool you, it is quite simple - just a bit verbose for readability (self documenting code ftw right?)

Also I should mention that the language here is [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/), but as always, it is straightforward to convert it to JS.

Answer (score 1):

For those using MooTools, here is equivalent code:

```
            'mousewheel': function(event){
            var height = this.getSize().y;
            height -= 2;    // Not sure why I need this bodge
            if ((this.scrollTop === (this.scrollHeight - height) && event.wheel < 0) || 
                (this.scrollTop === 0 && event.wheel > 0)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
```

Bear in mind that I, like some others, had to tweak a value by a couple of px, that is what the height -= 2 is for.

Basically the main difference is that in MooTools, the delta info comes from event.wheel instead of an extra parameter passed to the event.

Also, I had problems if I bound this code to anything (event.target.scrollHeight for a bound function does not equal this.scrollHeight for a non-bound one)

Hope this helps someone as much as this post helped me ;)

Comment: although i know nothing about your code, i'm willing to bet you had to subtract 2 from the height because ```getSize()``` doesn't account for the border (which in your case was 1px on both top and bottom).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Leland Kwong's](http://codepen.io/LelandKwong/pen/edAmn/) code.

Basic idea is to bind the wheeling event to the child element, and then  use the native javascript property `scrollHeight` and the jquery property `outerHeight` of the child element to detect the end of the scroll, upon which `return false` to the wheeling event to prevent any scrolling.

```
var scrollableDist,curScrollPos,wheelEvent,dY;
$('#child-element').on('wheel', function(e){
  scrollableDist = $(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).outerHeight();
  curScrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
  wheelEvent = e.originalEvent;
  dY = wheelEvent.deltaY;
  if ((dY>0 && curScrollPos >= scrollableDist) ||
      (dY<0 && curScrollPos <= 0)) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice, keeping it "local" - but what if deltaY is "chunky" - won't the last 20-30px remain hidden then ?

Answer (score 1):

I yoinked this from the chosen library: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/blob/master/coffee/chosen.jquery.coffee

```
function preventParentScroll(evt) {
    var delta = evt.deltaY || -evt.wheelDelta || (evt && evt.detail)
    if (delta) {
        evt.preventDefault()
        if (evt.type ==  'DOMMouseScroll') {
            delta = delta * 40  
        }
        fakeTable.scrollTop = delta + fakeTable.scrollTop
    }
}
var el = document.getElementById('some-id')
el.addEventListener('mousewheel', preventParentScroll)
el.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventParentScroll)
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for this for MooTools and this was the first that came up.
The original MooTools example would work with scrolling up, but not scrolling down so I decided to write this one.

- MooTools 1.4.5: http://jsfiddle.net/3MzFJ/
- MooTools 1.3.2: http://jsfiddle.net/VhnD4/
- MooTools 1.2.6: http://jsfiddle.net/xWrw4/

---

```
var stopScroll = function (e) {
    var scrollTo = null;
    if (e.event.type === 'mousewheel') {
        scrollTo = (e.event.wheelDelta * -1);
    } else if (e.event.type === 'DOMMouseScroll') {
        scrollTo = 40 * e.event.detail;
    }
    if (scrollTo) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.scrollTo(0, scrollTo + this.scrollTop);
    }
    return false;
};
```

**Usage:**

```
(function)($){
    window.addEvent('domready', function(){
        $$('.scrollable').addEvents({
             'mousewheel': stopScroll,
             'DOMMouseScroll': stopScroll
        });
    });
})(document.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery plugin with emulate natural scrolling for Internet Explorer

```
  $.fn.mousewheelStopPropagation = function(options) {
    options = $.extend({
        // defaults
        wheelstop: null // Function
        }, options);

    // Compatibilities
    var isMsIE = ('Microsoft Internet Explorer' === navigator.appName);
    var docElt = document.documentElement,
        mousewheelEventName = 'mousewheel';
    if('onmousewheel' in docElt) {
        mousewheelEventName = 'mousewheel';
    } else if('onwheel' in docElt) {
        mousewheelEventName = 'wheel';
    } else if('DOMMouseScroll' in docElt) {
        mousewheelEventName = 'DOMMouseScroll';
    }
    if(!mousewheelEventName) { return this; }

    function mousewheelPrevent(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        if('function' === typeof options.wheelstop) {
            options.wheelstop(event);
        }
    }

    return this.each(function() {
        var _this = this,
            $this = $(_this);
        $this.on(mousewheelEventName, function(event) {
            var origiEvent = event.originalEvent;
            var scrollTop = _this.scrollTop,
                scrollMax = _this.scrollHeight - $this.outerHeight(),
                delta = -origiEvent.wheelDelta;
            if(isNaN(delta)) {
                delta = origiEvent.deltaY;
            }
            var scrollUp = delta < 0;
            if((scrollUp && scrollTop <= 0) || (!scrollUp && scrollTop >= scrollMax)) {
                mousewheelPrevent(event);
            } else if(isMsIE) {
                // Fix Internet Explorer and emulate natural scrolling
                var animOpt = { duration:200, easing:'linear' };
                if(scrollUp && -delta > scrollTop) {
                    $this.stop(true).animate({ scrollTop:0 }, animOpt);
                    mousewheelPrevent(event);
                } else if(!scrollUp && delta > scrollMax - scrollTop) {
                    $this.stop(true).animate({ scrollTop:scrollMax }, animOpt);
                    mousewheelPrevent(event);
                }
            }
        });
    });
};
```

https://github.com/basselin/jquery-mousewheel-stop-propagation/blob/master/mousewheelStopPropagation.js

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Great job Tiben. Thanks for that, really. +1 for the effort

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could find was listening to the scroll event on the window and set the scrollTop to the previous scrollTop if the child div was visible.

```
prevScrollPos = 0
$(window).scroll (ev) ->
    if $('#mydiv').is(':visible')
        document.body.scrollTop = prevScrollPos
    else
        prevScrollPos = document.body.scrollTop
```

There is a flicker in the background of the child div if you fire a lot of scroll events, so this could be tweaked, but it is hardly noticed and it was sufficient for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `overflow: hidden;` on `body`. It automatically scrolls everything to the top. There's no need for JavaScript either. Make use of `overflow: auto;`:

## HTML Structure

```
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="overlay-content"></div>
</div>

<div class="background-content">
    lengthy content here
</div>
```

## Styling

```
.overlay{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);

    .overlay-content {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
}

.background-content{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Play with the demo [here](http://luxiyalu.com/playground/overlay/).

Comment: I can't get this to work - there's a million lines of CSS and JS in your playground

Comment: I recommend using `overflow: hidden;` on `body` as long as it doesn't scroll to the top of the page automatically. But when it does scroll to the top automatically, you should try using `overflow: auto; height: 100%` on `body`.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a funny trick to lock the parent's `scrollTop` when mouse hovers over a scrollable element. This way you don't have to implement your own wheel scrolling.

Here's an example for preventing document scroll, but it can be adjusted for any element.

```
scrollable.mouseenter(function ()
{
  var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
  $(document).on('scroll.trap', function ()
  {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() != scroll) $(document).scrollTop(scroll);
  });
});

scrollable.mouseleave(function ()
{
  $(document).off('scroll.trap');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[M.K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328072/mk) offered a great plugin in his answer. Plugin can be found [**here**](http://mohammadyounes.github.io/jquery-scrollLock/#demo). However, for the sake of completion, I thought it'd be a good idea to put it together in one answer for AngularJS.

1. Start by injecting the bower or npm (whichever is preferred)

   ```
   bower install jquery-scrollLock --save
   npm install jquery-scroll-lock --save
   ```
2. Add the following directive. I am choosing to add it as an attribute

   ```
   (function() {
      'use strict';

       angular
          .module('app')
          .directive('isolateScrolling', isolateScrolling);

          function isolateScrolling() {
              return {
                  restrict: 'A',
                  link: function(sc, elem, attrs) {
                     $('.scroll-container').scrollLock();
                  }
              }
          }
   })();
   ```
3. And the important piece the plugin fails to document in their website is the HTML structure that it must follow.

   ```
   <div class="scroll-container locked">
       <div class="scrollable" isolate-scrolling>
            ... whatever ...
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

The attribute `isolate-scrolling` must contain the `scrollable` class and it all needs to be inside the `scroll-container` class or whatever class you choose and the `locked` class must be cascaded.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth to mention that with modern frameworks like reactJS, AngularJS, VueJS, etc, there are easy solutions for this problem, when dealing with fixed position elements. Examples are side panels or overlaid elements.

The technique is called a "Portal", which means that one of the components used in the app, without the need to actually extract it from where you are using it, will mount its children at the bottom of the body element, outside of the parent you are trying to avoid scrolling.

Note that it will not avoid scrolling the body element itself. You can combine this technique and mounting your app in a scrolling div to achieve the expected result.

Example Portal implementation in React's material-ui: https://material-ui-next.com/api/portal/

Answer (score 0):

There is ES 6 crossbrowser + mobile vanila js decision:

```
function stopParentScroll(selector) {
    let last_touch;
    let MouseWheelHandler = (e, selector) => {
        let delta;
        if(e.deltaY)
            delta = e.deltaY;
        else if(e.wheelDelta)
            delta = e.wheelDelta;
        else if(e.changedTouches){
            if(!last_touch){
                last_touch = e.changedTouches[0].clientY;
            }
            else{
                if(e.changedTouches[0].clientY > last_touch){
                    delta = -1;
                }
                else{
                    delta = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        let prevent = function() {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            e.returnValue = false;
            return false;
        };

        if(selector.scrollTop === 0 && delta < 0){
            return prevent();
        }
        else if(selector.scrollTop === (selector.scrollHeight - selector.clientHeight) && delta > 0){
            return prevent();
        }
    };

    selector.onwheel = e => {MouseWheelHandler(e, selector)}; 
    selector.onmousewheel = e => {MouseWheelHandler(e, selector)}; 
    selector.ontouchmove  = e => {MouseWheelHandler(e, selector)};
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution with mouseweel event:

```
$('.element').bind('mousewheel', function(e, d) {
    console.log(this.scrollTop,this.scrollHeight,this.offsetHeight,d);
    if((this.scrollTop === (this.scrollHeight - this.offsetHeight) && d < 0)
        || (this.scrollTop === 0 && d > 0)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try it this way:

```
$('#element').on('shown', function(){ 
   $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
   $('body').css('margin-left', '-17px');
});

$('#element').on('hide', function(){ 
   $('body').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
   $('body').css('margin-left', '0px');
});
```