# Prevent scrolling in Browser without overflow hidden

Tags: jquery, browser, popup, scroll

I have scrollable content in a popup on a page. If the bottom of the content in that popup is reached via scrolling, the scroll of the body should not happen, it should be locked, as long as the focus is in the popup.

I could just apply an temorary overflow:hidden to the body, but that would hide the main scrollbar of the body completely and make the page "shift", which I dont like to happen.

You can see what I mean in this testcase: http://jsfiddle.net/wVPDU/

Any ideas to fix this issue with may well with javascript/jQuery?

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802467/prevent-scrolling-of-parent-element

Comment: that seems to be the case. thank you for the link.