# how to stop iframe changes from changing parent window position

Tags: iframe, google-docs

I created a mortgage calculator in Google Docs and embedded it in an iframe. However, any change made in the calculator, or even scrolling in the iframe scrolls the parent page back up to the top. How do I stop this behavior?
Page is [Mortgage Prepayment Calculator](http://clubthrifty.com/mortgage-prepayment-calculator-loan-payoff-calculator/)

Comment: just a comment - maybe you should initialise your values to 0s the hashNUM looks really bad

Comment: you might find an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802467/prevent-scrolling-of-parent-element