# Vertical scroll bug in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JcUxs/1/)**

Trying to vertically scroll the div `child` in Google Chrome, arrived at the end, if you try to continue the scroll is also scrolled the div `parent`, which does not happen with Mozilla. How to fix it?

Comment: this might be what you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802467/prevent-scrolling-of-parent-element

Comment: The problem I've seen is here too, but I have not figured out how to solve with pure javascript, or perhaps (better) css... http://jsbin.com/ixura3/3

Comment: what version of google chrome do you use? It's working well for me on jsFiddle. I'm working with version 29.

Comment: I have tried both on Chrome 29 (Win), and Chrome 29 (Linux). The problem is that scroll to the end of the div child, if you continue scroll is also scroll the parent div, and I do not want this. Do you want a gif for you to see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you can disable the overflow when mouse is over the child div.
This way works on Firefox 24 for Mint, and Chromium 28...

http://jsfiddle.net/JcUxs/2/

```
$('.child').on('mouseover',function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('fixoverflow');
});

$('.child').on('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).parent().removeClass('fixoverflow');
});
```

css:

```
.fixoverflow{
    overflow: hidden
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks you, it works, but a solution in css maybe to add in the body to solve the problem is not there?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is the best solution I can achieve (It took 1 hour to understand that the scroll event and the wheel is getting trigger both):

I used flag variable to keep the scroller position.
I used jquery and I noticed just now from the comments that you asked for pure javascript.
Anyway jquery bases on native javascript so I'll edit my answer later and translate it to pure code.

Just confirm that it's good enough for you and i'll translate it.

**JavscriptCode:**

```
var isCanceled = false;
var currentPos = $(".parent").scrollTop();
var stopWheelTimer = undefined;

$(".child").on('mousewheel', function (event) {
    clearTimeout(stopWheelTimer);
    event.stopPropagation();
    isCanceled = true;
    currentPos = $(".parent").scrollTop();
    stopWheelTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        isCanceled = false;        
    }, 250);

});
$(".parent").on('mousewheel', function (elem) {
   if(isCanceled)
   {
       $(elem.target).scrollTop(currentPos);
   }
}); 
$(".parent").on('scroll', function (elem) {
   if(isCanceled)
   {
       $(elem.target).scrollTop(currentPos);
    }
});
```

Working Example: 
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JcUxs/4/)