# Scrolling child div makes parent div scrolls

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following test page:

(didn't post code 'cause would be too big)
As noticed, when you finish scrolling the little div in the bottom, the main div also scrolls. Is there anything, propriety to disable this behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the `overflow` property is one way.

Comment: I'm already using it on the child div.

Comment: This is default browser behaviour

Comment: But Facebook, Google Plus, etc doesn't behave like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the plugin mentioned on this question:

[Prevent scrolling of parent element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802467/prevent-scrolling-of-parent-element)

Or take a look at the JS here (not my code). This code adds classes to the children and traps the scroll event which can be used to prevent the parent from scrolling.

http://codepen.io/LelandKwong/pen/edAmn

```
var trapScroll;

(function($){  

 trapScroll = function(opt){

var trapElement;
var scrollableDist;
var trapClassName = 'trapScroll-enabled';
var trapSelector = '.trapScroll';

var trapWheel = function(e){

  if (!$('body').hasClass(trapClassName)) {

    return;

  } else {  

    var curScrollPos = trapElement.scrollTop();
    var wheelEvent = e.originalEvent;
    var dY = wheelEvent.deltaY;

    // only trap events once we've scrolled to the end
    // or beginning
    if ((dY>0 && curScrollPos >= scrollableDist) ||
        (dY<0 && curScrollPos <= 0)) {

      opt.onScrollEnd();
      return false;

    }

  }
      }

$(document)
  .on('wheel', trapWheel)
  .on('mouseleave', trapSelector, function(){

    $('body').removeClass(trapClassName);

  })
  .on('mouseenter', trapSelector, function(){   

    trapElement = $(this);
    var containerHeight = trapElement.outerHeight();
    var contentHeight = trapElement[0].scrollHeight; // height of scrollable content
    scrollableDist = contentHeight - containerHeight;

    if (contentHeight>containerHeight)
      $('body').addClass(trapClassName); 

  });       
} 

})($);

 var preventedCount = 0;
var showEventPreventedMsg = function(){  
  $('#mousewheel-prevented').stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 'fast');
}
var hideEventPreventedMsg = function(){
  $('#mousewheel-prevented').stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 'fast');
}
var addPreventedCount = function(){
  $('#prevented-count').html('prevented <small>x</small>' + preventedCount++);
}

trapScroll({ onScrollEnd: addPreventedCount });
$('.trapScroll')
  .on('mouseenter', showEventPreventedMsg)
  .on('mouseleave', hideEventPreventedMsg);      
$('[id*="parent"]').scrollTop(100);
```