# Preventing the scrolling going out of a dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `dropdown` with a scrolling content. The thing is, if I hover the content in the `dropdown` and starts to scroll, it scroll the content nicely but once arrived at the end it switches back to scrolling the page, but I would like the scrolling to be deactivated at this point.
To rephrase this, if hovering the `dropdown content`, preventing the scrolling to affect the whole page (window)

Anyway to achieve this ?

Here is an [example](http://output.jsbin.com/ixura3/3) with my problem reproduced

Comment: Please add your code that you tried.

Comment: you can use Brandon's mousewheel http://brandon.aaron.sh/code/mousewheel/docs, I think what you are looking for is preventing scrolling of parent element when you are in focus of a child element. check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802467/prevent-scrolling-of-parent-element

Comment: That's what I'd expect any page to do.  Please don't break my browsing experience.

Comment: @JamesThorpe agreed thousand times. Some developers seems designers, and they like to break usability, accessibility and user experience

Comment: @JamesThorpe Sorry but this is not a debate about whether the default behavior is correct or not. This is simply a question to feed my curiosity.

Comment: @JimishParekh Thanks I will have a look at this post.