# stopPropagation on ion-scroll when i scroll on the table element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, ionic-framework, stoppropagation

I have 2 table inside a ion-scroll element made with angularJs:

```
<ion-view>
     <ion-scroll class="has-header has-footer" scrollbar-y="false" direction="y">
         <div ng-controller="calendCtrl" >
            <div id="t1" class="CSSTableGenerator" >
                <table class="planner" isolateScrolling>
                     <tr ng-repeat="row in calendarData track by $index">
                        <td colspan="{{day.colspan}}" title="{{day.title}}" 
                            ng-class="day.class" 
                            ng-click="calendarCellClick($parent.$index,$index)"  
                            ng-repeat="day in row track by $index">
                             {{day.descr}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div id="t2" class="CSSTableGenerator" >
                <table class="planner" isolateScrolling>
                     <tr ng-repeat="row in calendarData track by $index">
                        <td colspan="{{day.colspan}}" title="{{day.title}}" 
                            ng-class="day.class" 
                            ng-click="calendarCellClick($parent.$index,$index)"  
                            ng-repeat="day in row track by $index">
                             {{day.descr}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

         <div>
    </ion-scroll>
</ion-view>
```

This 2 tables are realy long so i need an overflow scroll for both, but i need a ion-scroll to see both the table.

On Chrome Browser if i scroll when my mouse pointer is on the first table, i can scroll the first table but the ion-scroll element scroll too.

On safari, on the iPad i can scroll only the ion-scroll view but i can't do the same with the tables.

How can i manage that?

**UPDATE 1**

On a Firefox&Chrome a [stopPropagation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20894131/1373229) directive solve the double scroll behavior, but the table on iPad still unscrollable.

**UPDATE 2**

I have the same problem with the iPad scroll in a select input element on a long form, where i can scroll the form but not the select.

Comment: Are you using some Angular module for table? Could you share some more pieces of code?

Comment: @vpplat no module used

Comment: what's the `isolateScrolling` directive in your tables? And can you share a sample for calendarData?

Comment: read the link on update

Answer (score 0):

[Ionic 1.2](http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-ionic-1-2/) have fixed a lot of bug on the buggy browser scroll world.

Using 1.2.4 installed from bower, everything now work how aspected.

The only things that doesn't work to me, is the attribute `scrollbar-y="false"` that not hide the scrollbar.

What follow is the css of the table:

```
table.planner {
    overflow-y: auto; 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

It works on Safari iPad2 with `overflow-y: scroll;` too.