# How to keep background fixed irrespective of scrollbar?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I am writing a small scrollbar on a div [basically a pop up div] like:

```
#scrollableDiv
    {
        position:absolute;
        width:250px;
        height: 450px;
        padding:12px;
        display:none;
        margin-top:-1px;
        border-top:0px;
        overflow:auto;
        border:2px #CCC solid;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #EEEEF1;
        color: black;
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 100;
    }
```

The issue is as soon the scrollbar reaches the end of div, it starts scrolling the body at the back as well vertically.Is there a way to prevent this using css or jquery or anything?

Comment: background-attachment: fixed;

Comment: nope, doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent scrolling of parent element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802467/prevent-scrolling-of-parent-element)

Comment: how do i use that

Comment: @NehaBajpai refer the linked question..

Comment: can you post your whole code (keep it to minimum)?