# How to prevent executing window.onpopstate function while window.scroll event using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The scenario is when I scroll in browser it executes

```
$(window).scroll(function() { ...  }
```

but in same page I have onpopstate function which usually executes when I press back/forward button in browser

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) { ...  }
```

Here is my complete script on html page

```
<script>
    window.onpopstate = function(event) { ...  }

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() { ...  }
    });
</script>
```

Issue is when I scroll in browser it executes `$(window).scroll` as well as `window.onpopstate` both the events.

Can anyone help me out here, as how do I prevent executing `window.onpopstate` event while scrolling.

Comment: have you tried function(e) e.preventDefault();?

Comment: this so post may be helpful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802467/prevent-scrolling-of-parent-element

Comment: @Anil : Where do I need to keep "e.preventDefault();" basically ?

Comment: we should do in first event; say as first statement, to omit event's default behavior, like raise next event etc. $(window).scroll(function(e) {  e.preventDefault();  }.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$(window).scroll` event always raises the `popstate` event and we should not stop this by using event propagation, as A `popstate` event is dispatched to the window every time the active history entry changes between two history entries for the same document. refer details on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate)

The solution here can be be to put a check in `popstate` 's handler like
when `event.state is not null` then do your job else skip

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
        if (event.state) {
            -- do your job
        }
    }, false);
```

Comment: Thanks !! It works for me. Explanation is also acceptable. Good catch

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onpopstate = function(event) {
        alert("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
     }

     $(document).ready(function () {
         $(window).scroll(function () {
             alert(2);
         });
     });

     history.pushState({ page: 1 }, "title 1", "?page=1");   
     history.pushState({ page: 2 }, "title 2", "?page=2");   
     history.replaceState({ page: 3 }, "title 3", "?page=3");
     history.back(); 
     history.back();
     history.go(2);  
</script>
```

I also testing, but without this issue.

If you can provide detail code.

Comment: I have given the complete script in my question itself. The issue is when you scroll, it executes window.scroll function but also executes "onpopstate" function which I want to prevent.