# How to capture the scroll event on a div to only scroll the top-most (by z-index) component

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've illustrated the problem I'm describing in a Codepen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KZOwdm?editors=1111

I have a title bar at the top of my page that with a fixed position at the top of the page (`position: fixed;`).

The main content of my page is a scrollable list with a `margin-top` to make sure it stays below the title bar.  Clicking on any of these items brings in a `slide-up`, which is a `position: fixed;` div with `z-index: 2;` that covers the whole page from just below the title bar down to the bottom of the screen.

I'm having problems with scroll on this `slide-up`.  I expect that scrolling over the slide-up would scroll only that div's content, rather than the entire page (including the contents underneath).  This is especially frustrating when the contents underneath are very long.  What I'm seeing is that once scrolling completes on the slide-up, the parent div starts scrolling.

In a typical scenario, this slide-up would be meant to cover the page, sort of like displaying a "new page".  So, I would not expect the parent div to come into the equation at all when scrolling over the slide-up div.  The second problem here is that scrolling on a mobile device seems to *only* scroll the parent, not the slide-up.  How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You require two things:

1. **[`overflow-y: scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y)** on `.slide-up` in order to allow the contents to actually scroll
2. A **[`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)** small enough to allow the text to actually overflow the **total** `height`
   (not just what is visible).

Adding `overflow-y: scroll` and changing the `height` of `.slide-up` to **[`calc(100% - 40px)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)** (which accommodates for the `top`) showcases this in the following example:

```css
.tabs {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 40px;
  background: #f54;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 1em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.slide-up {
  z-index: 2;
  top: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #ffa000;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  width: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class='tabs'>
  <h5>Tabs</h5>
</div>
<div class='content'>
  <h5>Here is some random text to make this scroll</h5>
  <h5>This is the main content</h5>
  <h5>This is the main content</h5>
  <h5>This is the main content</h5>
  <h5>This is the main content</h5>
  <h5>This is the main content</h5>
  <h5>This is the main content</h5>
  <h5>This is the main content</h5>
  <h5>This is the main content</h5>
  <h5>This is the main content</h5>
  <h5>This is the main content</h5>
  <h5>This is the main content</h5>
  <h5>This is the main content</h5>
  <h5>This is the main content</h5>
  <h5>This is the main content</h5>
  <h5>This is the main content</h5>
</div>
<div class='slide-up'>
  <h5>Slide up content</h5>
  <h5>Slide up content</h5>
  <h5>Slide up content</h5>
  <h5>Slide up content</h5>
  <h5>Slide up content</h5>
  <h5>Slide up content</h5>
  <h5>Slide up content</h5>
  <h5>Slide up content</h5>
  <h5>Slide up content</h5>
  <h5>Slide up content end</h5>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response!  This still seems to fall victim to the fact that the parent starts scrolling when we've reached the end (at least on my machine).  Can this be helped?

Comment: That's because you would reach the end of the child content, and the parent element would gain 'focus'. It's possible to prevent that through JavaScript if truly necessary, though fairly cumbersome. Doing that is covered fairly extensively in [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802467/prevent-scrolling-of-parent-element) :)