# Child which scrolls vertically preventing parent div from scrolling horizontally

Tags: jquery, scroll, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I'm able to actually make a parent wrapper `div` scroll horizontally as intended but there are child `div` elements which need to be scrollable vertically. The issue is that whenever I enable the child `div` to scroll vertically, the parent `div` still continues to scroll horizontally. Any ideas on how to go about this?

The HTML is pretty straightforward:

```
<div id="wrapper">         <!-- This div scrolls horizontally -->
    <div class="child">    <!-- This div scrolls normally -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery is pretty much a mess but I'm willing to redo it because I'm still new at this and any pointers that can help will be appreciated:

```
$('#wrapper').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){
    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail)));
    event.preventDefault();

    // Scrollleft on mousewheel
    $(this).scrollLeft( $(this).scrollLeft() - ( delta * 90 ) );
});
```

I don't know what to add to it to make sure scrolling the `#child` element will scroll it normally (vertically) and prevent the `#wrapper` from scrolling at all. I could enable the `#child` scrolling but for some reason the `#wrapper` still scrolls once before stopping, which means there's a second where both `#child` and `#wrapper` scroll at the same time and then the `#wrapper` stops while the `#child` continues.

Comment: can you make a fiddle or code snippet from your code sample? Then we can investigate what actually happens.

Comment: You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802467/prevent-scrolling-of-parent-element-when-inner-element-scroll-position-reaches-t